# Compile error when doing Maven install

Tags: java, maven

I was trying to install the dependency packages into my location maven repository with running `mvn clean install` from my maven project.

But unfortunately. I got a compile error for some source files which said :`annotations are not supported in -source 1.3(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)@override`.

After researching. I found I need to specify the source version of my maven project.

So I add the following configuration in the `POM`.

```
<build>
     <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
     <plugins>
          <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
</build>
```

Actually. It does work fine. But what makes me confused is where does the `JDK1.6` comes from and make the Maven compile work ? I didn't have the `JDK1.6` install in my computer(Currently, the available JDK installed in my computer is `JDK1.8`), Thanks.

Comment: JDK 1.8 can produce code that will run on JRE 1.6

Comment: If you're running maven from Eclipse, then you're a victim of m2e plugin, which when importing projects by default makes them compatible to Java 1.5. However I don't know how could you get error for 1.3, may be it's related.

Comment: @11thdimension I just run maven from the console, not from Eclipse.

Comment: Check your Java version in the console. `java -version`, if it's `1.8` then check if you have the latest maven.

Comment: @11thdimension It is `1.8`, and the maven version is 2.2.1.

Comment: ok, now try with latest maven

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Later versions of Java allow you to compile your program as earlier versions. Since you have Java 8 installed you can compile your program as a Java 6 one that will run on a machine with only the 1.6 JRE. The limitation is that you can't use any of the language features added in the Java 7 and 8 releases.